# WordPress - Add/Edit Post Screen Options not showing Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, categories

this is hopefully a very simple fix but i just noticed on my Add New/Edit Post Screen Options i don't have Categories to Enable/Disable (see pic). Any help muchos appreciated!!

[image: Word Press 3.4.2 - Add/Edit Post Screen Options]

Comment: Is this a custom post type? You might not have a categories taxonomy setup. Also you might want to check your theme's `functions.php` file and see if anything is removing the categories from this post type.

Comment: Must be a plugin or something in `functions.php`. You could also try posting on [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

in `wp-admin/includes/screen.php` we see:

```
<div class="metabox-prefs">
    <?php
        meta_box_prefs( $this ); // draw checkboxes in screen options
    ?>
</div>
```

and `meta_box_prefs` function takes in account the `get_hidden_meta_boxes` function:

```
function meta_box_prefs( $screen ) {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    $hidden = get_hidden_meta_boxes($screen);

    // hide some boxes
}
```

An this function includes 2 filters `default_hidden_meta_boxes` and `hidden_meta_boxes`:

```
function get_hidden_meta_boxes( $screen ) {
    // code
    $hidden = apply_filters( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', $hidden, $screen );
    // code
    return apply_filters( 'hidden_meta_boxes', $hidden, $screen, $use_defaults );
}
```

---

Mi conclusion is that **one of your plugins is hiding `categories`** in your `screen options`.

Comment: Thanks mate, i've skipped this issue for now and will come back to it later this eve. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome, try to deactivate suspicious plugins and see.

Comment: Been a while since i addressed this issue. Deactivating all the plugins made no difference :-/ any other ideas?