# Categories option not appearing in post meta box

Tags: php, wordpress

While create new post in WordPress,

categories options not visible in screen options.

where i can find to show categories option while add new post?

Comment: Check the top of the page (when edit the post), somwhere there is a button what is brings you a panel, where you can tick on/off what you want to see or not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with developement. You should ask your question on the Wordpress.com or .org forum.

Comment: @lolka_bolka category checkbox not appearing in the top of the page in Screen Options.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674827/wordpress-add-edit-post-screen-options-not-showing-categories